# Is there any math utility method to calculate the following expression?

Tags: java

Is there any math utility method to calculate the following expression? Basically, I need to find the largest integer less than or equal to x which can be divided by N evenly.

```
  x - x % N; // N is an integer.
```

Comment: What about e.g., `-56` and `10`? `-56 - (-56) % 10` evaluates to `-60`—is it what you expect?

Comment: isn't it integer `x / N`? Not sure about java, but that's what I would expect if your `x` is integer.

Comment: If `x` is an integer too, why don't you just the code you posted?

Comment: @MichaelKrelin-hacker I assume he wants to get `N * (x/N)` in that case which would yield `-50` for `x = -56` and `n = 10`, since `-56/10 = -5`.

Comment: Well, yes, I didn't make enough sense.

Answer (score 4):

For positive integers:  (x / N) * N.

(If it needs to be strictly less than x vs <= x then use ((x-1)/N) * N, for x > 0.)

Comment: Works for all integer values of x and N where N != 0, as long as the problem definition is integer with largest absolute value closer to zero than 'x'

Comment: Likely, but it makes my head hurt to work through all the cases.

Comment: I had to edit my comment a bit, as the logic is inverted when x less than 0. When x is negative it will find the smallest integer greater than x.

Comment: One reason why I limited things to positive numbers is that it's not clear whether the OP wanted "smaller" arithmetically or smaller in magnitude.  And then there's the whole issue of how division works with negative numbers -- my memory of those slightly arcane rules is always a little shaky.

Answer (score 2):

if x is a positive integer and N a power of 2 you can do x & -N

EDIT: its -n not 2-n , thanks to Peter Lawrey for pointing that out

Comment: Yeah, if N is a power of 2 you can do some really strange (and cryptic) rounding operations.  (Always comment such logic well since even you won't understand it 3 months later.)

Answer (score 0):

If x is a positive integer then you can use

```
int result = x - x % N;
```

or

```
int result = (x/N)*N;
```

If x is a positive double then you can use

```
int result = N * (int)(x/N);
```